# PlayStation 3 not detecting any game discs

Tags: ps3

So I was playing Ninja Gaiden Sigma 2 and the game froze (which happens quite often) so I restarted the PS3 and now it is not detecting any discs (games, dvds, cds). I can hear the drive make sounds. What should I do?

I have tried the restore menu -> fix filesystem to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be obvious, but have you tried turning it off completely from the socket, and the starting it again?
Also - if it is causing problems with disk detection, then try a disk head cleaner disk - there should be a DVD one of these.

Comment: i tried this. Now I have to pay 50% price of a new ps3 to get a new one. sucks :(

Comment: Not sure if this is cheaper - but have you tried somebody like this: http://www.psr1.com/. Thinking a bit more about your question, it is unlikely to be simple dirty heads, but more likely that something has overheated while you played a game and is now failing.

Comment: since I am in india, that option is not available :(

Comment: ultimately I ended up paying for the new one, but I guess this is a helpful answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem once. We smoke a lot in my living room, so the lens of the laser was dirty. I disassembled the PS3 (warranty was expired anyways) and the BluRay drive and cleaned the lens with a Q-Tip and some lens cleaner fluid.

Works like a charm since then.

It's really not hard and you can find videos on YouTube that show you how to disassemble both: PS3 and BluRay drive